# How to show events between a start and end date by selecting any date in between

Tags: php, mysql, date

Event A is happening between 24th to 29th date of a month. If user select any date after 24 and before 29. Is there a way to show Event A

I am using this query if user select 25th and 27th.

```
Select * 
from Events 
where DateFrom >= '25-01-2019' and DateTo <= '27-01-2019'
```

It will not show Event A because its start date and end date are different.

Example Data

```
 id  name             DateFrom           DateTo 
 1   Music eventA     2019-01-24       2019-01-29
 2   Music eventB     2019-01-25        2019-01-30
```

If user select DateFrom '2019-01-26' and DateTo '2019-01-27' I want to show event with id=1 as 26 and 27 lies between 24 to 29

Comment: have you used date()from mysql ?

Comment: The query i am using is in the question. I have not used date function

Comment: try this Select * 
from Events 
where DATE(DateFrom) >= '25-01-2019' and DATE(DateTo) <= '27-01-2019'

Comment: When using dates in MySQL, always use the MySQL date format `where DateFrom >= '2019-01-25' and DateTo <= '2019-01-27'`. Putting `DATE` around fields ruins index usage.

Comment: eventB also lies between 24 to 29 than

Comment: that is okay if event B is also selected

Answer (score 1):

The selected start date (`2019-01-26`) should be compared with the `DateFrom` of the data, while the selected end date (`2019-01-27`) should be compared with the `DateTo`, as mentioned in this query,

```
SELECT * 
FROM Events 
WHERE DateFrom <= '2019-01-26' 
AND DateTo >= '2019-01-27';
```

Using the following sample data, its working correct,

```
id  name                DateFrom    DateTo
1   Some other event    2018-12-12  2018-12-31
2   Music Event A       2019-01-24  2019-01-29
3   Music eventB        2019-01-25  2019-01-30
4   Event C             2019-02-01  2019-02-09
```

The query above returns this,

```
id  name            DateFrom    DateTo
2   Music Event A   2019-01-24  2019-01-29
3   Music eventB    2019-01-25  2019-01-30
```

Hope it answers your question!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all events that "happen" or "partially happen" in your selected range of dates you could do

```
Select * from Events 
where DateFrom <= '2019-01-27' and DateTo  >= '2019-01-25'
```

In case you only want those events that are happing in the full span of your specified dates you need to do

```
Select * from Events 
where DateFrom <= '2019-01-25' and DateTo  >= '2019-01-27'
```

Instead of using the string format `'2019-01-25'` you could also use the numeric date format `20190125`. Both forms should work equally well.

Comment: The idea is to select events lies between 24 and 29 as 25th and 27th are selected. if we use this query DateFrom <= '2019-01-25' and DateTo  >= '2019-01-27' because of first condition it will also select 23,22,21...

Comment: ... only if the end date qualifies the second condition `>='2019-01-27'`.

Comment: is it possible to show events happening only between 24 to 29 if 25 and 27 is selected

Answer (score 0):

Please update your query as below. Dates are not passed correctly in the query.

```
Select * 
from Events 
where ( DateFrom >= '25-01-2019' and DateFrom <= '27-01-2019') and 
      ( DateTo >= '25-01-2019' and DateTo <= '27-01-2019' ).
```

Comment: DateFrom >= '25-01-2019' and DateFrom <= '27-01-2019'  this will not pick 24-01-2019